# Ubuntu 18.10 delivers ugly fonts

Tags: fonts, 18.10

Fonts are blurry and ugly almost everywhere except Gnome : 
google chrome, intellij idea etc.

Ubuntu 18.10 ships with:

```
libcairo 1.15.12
libfreetype 2.8.1
fontconfig 2.13
fontconfig-config 2.13
```

I tried:

```
libfreetype 2.9.1
```

and infinality fontconfig packages.

But nothing from above solved the problem.

**EDIT**

Also, i tried next settings for `/etc/fonts/local.conf`:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <!-- 
    These are the true system defaults that will override ones from `gnome-tweaks`.
    Unfortunately, `gnome-tweaks` does not provide all of these options in the UI. Without them "full" style hinting looks weird - doesn't seem to use BCI-hinting or attempts to enable both and ends up with a mess. Anyway, this fixes it.
     -->
    <match target="font">
        <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
            <const>hintfull</const>
        </edit>
        <!--
        Italic variants look jagged without forcing the DPI. Default DPI of FreeType is 72. Verify with `fc-match` if in doubt.
         -->
        <edit name="dpi" mode="assign">
            <int>96</int>
        </edit>
    </match>

    <!-- This enables the autohinter for known-bad fonts without hinting instructions regardless of system defaults above -->
    <include>60-group-non-tt-fonts.conf</include>
    <!-- This marks known-good fonts with a tag -->
    <include>61-group-tt-fonts.conf</include>
    <!-- This ensures that known-good fonts will have the right options set regardless of system defaults above -->
    <include>62-group-tt-rendering.conf</include>
</fontconfig>
```

but it only aggravated the situation

**UPDATE**

This is due to upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10.
I just tested fresh install of 18.10 on my laptop and there is no problems with fonts.

My guess that this issue relates to fonts configs, which didn't replaced with new ones during upgrade or conflicts in some places.

However, this doesn't mean there are no problems with fonts at all.
On my newly fresh install of 18.10 (laptop) Telegram starts for about 2-3 minutes as it can't find necessary fonts in specific place.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: very bad font font vscode and telegram